# Получение данных из БД через join

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Пытаюсь вывести из БД записи через join, но почему-то срабатывает только на один параметр в массиве, если больше, то не выдает ничего.

```php
$data->join("property_product", function ($join) use ($filter) {
    $join->on("product.id", "=", "property_product.id_product");
    foreach ($filter['property'] as $keyp => $valuep) {
        $join->where("property_product.id_property", "=", $valuep['id_property']);
    }
});
```

По записям в БД все есть, все должно работать. Если я делаю без foreach

```php
$join->where("property_product.id_property", "=", $filter['property'][0]['id_property']);
```

или

```php
$join->where("property_product.id_property", "=", $filter['property'][1]['id_property']);
```

то все работает. То есть принимает только один where, со вторым уже ничего не работает.

```php
$filter['property'] = [["id_property" => 2], ["id_property" => 3]]
```

property_product

| id | id_product | id_property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |

product

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | name 1 |
| 2 | name 2 |
| 3 | name 3 |

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134325/discussion-on-question-by--------join).

Answer (score 0):

Замените в цикле

```
$join->where("property_product.id_property", "=", $valuep['id_property']);
```

на

```
$join->orWhere("property_product.id_property", "=", $valuep['id_property']);
```

Т.к. в первом случае у вас формируется такая структура `"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND ... AND ...)`, во втором же будет `"SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... OR ... OR ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, вам необходимо реализовать так называемый **фасетный поиск**, то есть получить *product*, имеющие все перечисленные *property*. В этом случае на каждый property должен быть отдельный join:

```php
foreach ($filter['property'] as $property) {
    $alias = 'property_product_' . $property['id_property'];
    $data->join("property_product as {$alias}", function ($join) use ($property, $alias) {
        $join->on("product.id", "=", "{$alias}.id_product")
            ->where("{$alias}.id_property", $property['id_property']);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понимаю, в Laravel есть более удобные способы сделать нечто подобное, например:

```
Product::whereHas('property_product', function($query) use ($idsProperties) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $idsProperties);
})->get();
```

Если бы вы точнее сформулировали вопрос, что вы хотите получить на выходе, ответ тоже был бы точнее..